# Error in JpaTransactionManager while using imported entities

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot project with 2 data sources. First uses entities from this project and I need a second data source that uses JPA entities imported as maven dependency from another project. I created 2 data sources using [this example](https://github.com/jahe/spring-boot-multiple-datasources/) . But I can't run project because of errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#69ebb490': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'createSharedEntityManager' parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] to required type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: 
Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I have following configuration for imported entities (I created the same package structure to put my services to the same package in my app as imported entities located):

```
import com.company.second.db.entities.MyImportedEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.company.second.db", "com.company.second.db.entities"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondTransactionManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory"
)
public class SecondDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class, hbm");
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.company.second.db", "com.company.second.db.entities")
            .properties(properties).packages(MyImportedEntity.class)
            .persistenceUnit("second")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager SecondTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("secondEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(secondEntityManagerFactory);
}

}
```

Example of imported entity:

```
package com.company.second.db.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_imported_entity")
public class MyImportedEntity {...}
```

Also, I try to configure Service to work with this imported entities:

```
package com.company.second.db.service.impl;

import com.company.second.db.entities.MyImportedEntity;
import com.company.second.db.entities.repository.MyImportedEntityRepository;
import com.company.second.db.service.MyImportedEntityService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Service
@Transactional(value = "secondTransactionManager", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyImportedEntityServiceImpl implements MyImportedEntityService { ... }
```

I have secondary configuration that is the same as secondary but with `@Primary` annotations. And it works fine without this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:

```
entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondTransactionManager",
transactionManagerRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory"
```

It looks like you have placed the beans wrong way, it should be:

```
entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager"
```

That's why `Spring` tries to: `convert value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'`